# Timestamp function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to create a function that would timestamp a cell. The way I want it to work is: when I turn a cell TRUE (with a checkbox) it fills a cell with text, then the cell right next to it will *timestamp when that happens*. The problem is that every time I open the sheet, my timestamp function updates to the *current date*.

It's my first time scripting in this language or in Sheets. I did my best to Google this first but I didn't find anything that quite fit what I was imagining. Anyone willing to help explain what I did wrong and how to fix it?

```
function timestamp(input){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var lastCell = cellRange.offset(0, -1);
  if( lastCell.getValue() === '' ){
    return('')
  } else{
    return(new Date());
  }

}
```

Also, if anyone has the time, I stripped these from another script I found on here but don't understand what they are needed for, can someone explain their purpose?:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
```

I couldn't get the function to run without it.

Comment: to customize my answer, please provide a spreadsheet

Comment: [Here is a quick sheet for example making](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PiMpEqZxvt5G_d_neSs8TKgnnOfUUfPXHSXQtl3ZS-A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: open script editor, paste the code inside, close the spreadsheet and reopen, then check the box, (do not put the function inside the cells) Take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVhPQ2WfOgHJINthg0E5Iz1EZJWSxVvvLjHlysTECtg/copy

Comment: Is there not a way to create it as a callable function within the sheet? That was my goal but if not I can make do this way as well.

Comment: no, because this way the timestamp will be continuously updated

Answer (score 0):

To put a timestamp when you check you can use onEdit function, for instance

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if ((r.getColumn() == 1) && (r.getValue() == true)){ 
    r.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```